Code for Google Colab will not transfer over to Jupyter Notebook
I am working on trying to work with BigDFT, which is a library dedicated to computational chemistry. The course is done through Google Colab, but I try to use Jupyter Notebook instead, due to the recommendations I've heard from most of my peers and it works most of the time. However, I have found a cell of code that it works on Colab, but not Jupyter.
install = "full_suite" #@param ["full_suite", "client (Google drive)", "client"]
install_var=install
!wget https://gitlab.com/luigigenovese/bigdft-school/-/raw/main/packaging/install.py &> /dev/null
args={'locally': True} if install == 'client' else {}
import install
getattr(install,install_var.split()[0])(**args)

When it's applied to Colab, it works well. When Jupyter uses it, I get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 import Install.py
2 install = "full_suite" #@param ["full_suite", "client (Google drive)", "client"]
3 install_var=install
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Install'
Is there something I can do to be able to do this on Jupyter?
Thank you
It ran easily on Colab and here is the success result:
Executing: pip install -q condacolab
✨✨ Everything looks OK!
Executing: mkdir -p /content
Executing: git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/BigDFT-group/bigdft-school
Error Occurred:
fatal: destination path 'bigdft-school' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Executing: mkdir -p /content/bigdft-school
Executing: conda install packaging/bigdft-suite-1.9.3_rc.2-mpi_openmpi_py37h008c211_0.tar.bz2
Downloading and Extracting Packages: ...working... done
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Executing: conda update --all
Error Occurred:
Channels:

conda-forge
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed

InvalidMatchSpec: Invalid spec 'bigdft-suite[url=file:///content/bigdft-school/packaging/bigdft-suite-1.9.3_rc.2-mpi_openmpi_py37h008c211_0.tar.bz2]': Libmamba only supports a subset of the MatchSpec interface for now. You can only use ('name', 'version', 'build', 'channel', 'subdir'), but you tried to use ('url',).

There's a comment in the README that looks to address this: "Such notebooks can also be executed on a local workstation with the bigdft-client installed. The installation can be performed by running the command: pip install pybigdft pyfutile py3dmol remotemanager". This though is below the information on typical use, and after a section targeted at 'experts' for a different reason. And so you may be better off in this case sticking with the suggested course of action at this time until you understand better things in play to port it over.

Thank you! I hate to sound dumb, but what would be the best way to use it afterward, or is does it have a client I should use?

(I forgot to put the link for that quote was from the repo github.com/BigDFT-group/bigdft-school. I also see it at luigigenovese/bigdft-school.)I'm hoping pybigdft or remotemanager cover it. I just ran that pip install command in my session launched from here via 'launch binder' badge and then in my notebook from BigDFT import Systems, which is that next line in the installation.ipynb notebook where you got the Google Colab-specific ...

 widget code, ran without issue.

And to get the data that is in the original code you shared, do this in the temporary session launched from the link I used above to 'launch binder' : run in a terminal git clone https://github.com/BigDFT-group/bigdft-school.git, then in the terminal run cd bigdft-school/ and then in the terminal run git checkout data. Now in the file navigator panel on the left double click on the folder bigdft-school and when it opens, you should see the 'data' folder listed there and be able to double click into the contents. You'll have to edit the path in any code to match those files.

Oh wait, that data it gets just seems to be placeholder because the files seem to be big and need git-lfs. Sorry. Looking into that more. I even got the install.data() method to work, like in install.data('data/session1.tar.xz') but it only gets the placeholder, too.

OPTION A. Using with the repo BigDFT-group/bigdft-school as the source of the notebooks and associated data
Getting the repo content & packages and setting up to make the install.data() steps work
We want to clone the repo to a temporary Jupyter session (served by the MyBinder service run by the Jupyter Community) to get started illustrating how to ultimately run this content outside Google Colab.
Go to here and press the 'launch binder' badge there. Or click here to launch a fresh session directly. (There originally was nothing special about this repo because it was made with the default template of the binder examples that includes environment.yml & so it was a good place to start & test a few things. Now I've added a few things to environment.yml and so I've made it its own repo.)
A fresh temporary Jupyter session should spin up. Except for a couple of packages pre-installed it is very fresh as it doesn't have any related content and many of the dependencies necessary. (I could have installed more of them but I wanted it to be more like a situation where you are just getting started using this software.)
Then open a terminal from the launcher.
In a terminal in the session run the following:
git clone https://github.com/BigDFT-group/bigdft-school.git
cd bigdft-school/
git checkout data
cd data/
git lfs fetch
git lfs install
git lfs checkout

That will get the repo and via the git lfs steps the content for the files too big to get originally.
This will also include getting the install.py file we'l run in a couple of steps.
Now run the following in the terminal install the software they say to install in the README:
pip install pybigdft pyfutile py3dmol remotemanager

That does much of what the line getattr(install,install_var.split()[0])(**args) in your original code block does. But not all. We'll tackle one of the key steps next.
By the way what the line getattr(install,install_var.split()[0])(**args) is doing is taking the setting toggled in the widget on Colab and running the corresponding function in installs.py and passing the arguments set, too.
Replacing the Executing: conda install packaging/bigdft-suite-1.9.3_rc.2-mpi_openmpi_py37h008c211_0.tar.bz2 step
In what you posted that it ran on Colabs, there is a line:
Executing: conda install packaging/bigdft-suite-1.9.3_rc.2-mpi_openmpi_py37h008c211_0.tar.bz2

I have added installing bigdft-suite from here when the session starts, equivalent of running conda install conda-forge::bigdft-suite, and that seems to handle it now there is no error saying bigdft is not recognized when the calculations notebook runs. You can verify it works by running bigdft --help in the terminal.
That should handle the rest of what getattr(install,install_var.split()[0])(**args) does I believe and tests with the specified notebooks seem to bear that out. but I'm still investigating. For the record getattr(install,install_var.split()[0])(**args) is what is kicking off what is shown under "It ran easily on Colab and here is the success result:". getattr(install,install_var.split()[0])(**args) is talking the selected full-suite or client info from the widget in the cell that only runs on colab and using that to look up the corresponding function in installs.py and running that selected function, passing it the arguments in args. The code in installs.py is pretty straightforward and so examining it in regards to those two functions should give insight into the individual steps and how I translated that over to performing corresponding steps in vanilla Jupyter using that and the information in the README that helped provide context, like "The installation can be performed by running the command pip install pybigdft pyfutile py3dmol remotemanager".
Replacing the import install
Now we are ready to run the notebooks.
(Alternatively, before running the code I suggest in this section, alter the 5th line in install.py to be data_url = 'https://gitlab.com/luigigenovese/bigdft-school/-/raw/main/'. This will allow the install.data() step to work without any extra help completing the unpacking step later because that source offers the complete files directly. See 'OPTION B' below to better understand why that is. I though cannot be sure the content is 100% the same between the two repos and so be cautious/compare.)
Double-click on the bigdft-school folder in the file navigation pane on the left.
Then double-click to go into the CCWinterSchool-2024 folder
Double click to pen either CCWinterSchool-2024/1.0.QuickStart.ipynb or CCWinterSchool-2024/1.B.Calculations.ipynb.
Now replace the code block you posted with the following in the Jupyter cell in CCWinterSchool-2024/1.0.QuickStart.ipynb or CCWinterSchool-2024/1.B.Calculations.ipynb:
#replacement for `import install` to target `../packaging/main/install.py` based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/8508004
import importlib.util
import sys
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("install", "../packaging/install.py")
install = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules["install"] = install
spec.loader.exec_module(install)

(You can add %pip install pybigdft pyfutile py3dmol remotemanager to that code block for the ones that also include the pip install line if you missed those installs earlier.)
(Note that actually this can be done in a simpler way in this case because it turns out install.py is self-contained and I discuss this at the bottom of this section.)
If you then run the following, you'll see the install.data() method now listed:
dir(install)

And install.data('data/session1.tar.xz') cell will run.
However, it will error out at the unpacking step. For example, that particular command will error at Executing: tar xJf session1.tar.xz -C .
That command will fail in that case because it only got the 'pointer file' for the LFS file.
However, we already got that actual data and can finish this ourselves since that supplied the command we need to unpack. The next section covers that.
Alternatively, you can use the following in a cell in the notebook as the replacement for getting the install.py file and running import install:
!cp ../packaging/main/install.py .
import install

That more directly is in line with the intentions of the following two lines of code from the original code block:
!wget https://gitlab.com/luigigenovese/bigdft-school/-/raw/main/packaging/install.py &> /dev/null
import install

Because this post title discusses implementing things to run in different places more in general, I put forth a more comprehensive and flexible option first. The one I suggested first would indeed still work if install.py was not self-contained and relied on importing further code from in the place it is located. So what I put forth, while not being as straightforward and easy to understand as the alternative two line version, would be more adaptable in other situations where you want to leave the file in its current location in the file hierarchy and still import from it, such as for importing the code for a full module that had been cloned in a repo along with some notebooks.
Another thing to consider is that in my case I copy the file because it is already present since the repo was cloned. You could use !wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BigDFT-group/bigdft-school/main/packaging/install.py or !curl -OL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BigDFT-group/bigdft-school/main/packaging/install.py or something similar to get the install.py file from a repo and place it in the current working directory. Or if !curl or !wget don't seem to work on your machine, as sometimes is the case with Windows, download the code for the install.py and copy it into the directory where the notebooks are, or the current working directory. Or upload it if you are using a remote session like MyBinder.org provides. Drag-and-drop from your local system into the file navigation pane on the left works to upload.
Completing the unpacking step that install.data() should have handled
I said in my comments earlier you need to adjust the path to point out the files in data with the content after using git-lfs to fetch it.
So now we have the command it is trying to run from earlier, and we just edit the path in that to match. So in CCWinterSchool-2024/1.0.QuickStart.ipynb or CCWinterSchool-2024/1.B.Calculations.ipynb make a new cell towards the top and put the following:
!tar xJf ../data/session1.tar.xz -C .

That will make scratch directory filled with dozens of files. You can get a sense of what is in in by running ls -lah scratch in the notebook in another cell.
Now you can run the cells below that point in CCWinterSchool-2024/1.0.QuickStart.ipynb or CCWinterSchool-2024/1.B.Calculations.ipynb after the install.data() steps and they will work.
If you make anything useful download it to your local machine ASAP as the session is temporary.
OPTION B. Using with the GitLab repo BigDFT-group/bigdft-school as the source of the notebooks and associated data
Turns out the source of content referenced in the original post had the GitLab repo BigDFT-group/bigdft-school which turns out to include most of the data content without needing git-lfs. Just one there seems to be listed as the LFS type. And so that makes the first part of the steps under OPTION A above easier if you aren't interested in that one file for now. It means you can run things, at least some of the initial steps, also in sessions where git-lfs isn't needed to be installed first, such as here.
So much of the first step would be replaced with just:
git clone https://gitlab.com/luigigenovese/bigdft-school.git
cd bigdft-school/

Then ls -lah data will show the specs for the actual content in the data directory.
I think the other steps are the same, but the install.data() step will work entirely, on its own, because in install.py it is data_url = 'https://gitlab.com/luigigenovese/bigdft-school/-/raw/main/'. However, I note the notebooks have some different content so be aware. Additionally, skip any code that is install.set_ready().

So I actually ran the code on the Google Colab as a whole, cell by cell, it actually came up with an error. So I guess I'll try to teach myself how to aspects of an easy diatomic molecule and see what happens lol

Thank you again, though. This does help me a lot. :)

I was mostly able to use it in vanilla Jupyter with two exceptions so far. One is the git-lfs stuff that I mentioned already. (Still hoping to investigate more because I don't yet see how Colab solves that.)  The other is when it does calculations, I'm seeing an error about log files that should be made. A lot of the initial notebooks in the Winter school list worked mostly besides that. I don't know what specific errors you are encountering on Google Colab? It's okay if you don't care to pursue that now but if it isn't one of the things I mentioned, I may already know a way past.

Progress. The git-lfs stuff was the key to more than I expected. Now in vanilla Jupyter I am able to run CCWinterSchool-2024/1.0.QuickStart.ipynb and CCWinterSchool-2024/1.B.Calculations.ipynb once I got the content install.data('data/session1.tar.xz') was meant to get and unpack and unpacked it correctly directly. I've put instructions for this now in the post.

I think it all works now at the new repo https://github.com/fomightez/bigdft-binder . Let me know if it still doesn't make sense to you? You should be able to adapt this to run on your own machine, too. I'm using the MyBinder system only because it makes it a good way to share and have a new fresh system.
